# How can I run `SET ROLE` automatically for postgres ActiveRecord migrations?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, rails-migrations

I'd like to setup app-specific users for a database, just for auditing/debugging purposes, but use the root "postgres" user role for table creation, since it already has the default privileges set up appropriately (and also because in my case, most of the tables are already owned by that user).

The app would only need this table creation/modification permission when running migrations, but I would be fine with them having it all the time if that's easier.  However, I haven't found *any* way to use `SET ROLE` successfully in Rails.

I thought it would work to add a new rake task that sets the role before the `db:migrate` task runs, like this:

```
# in lib/tasks/set_role.rake
namespace :db do
  task :set_role do
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET ROLE postgres")
  end
end

# in initializers/migration_hooks.rb
Rake::Task["db:migrate"].enhance ["db:set_role_postsgres"]
```

But that didn't work...

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure why the above didn't work, but I just had to put this all in the `.rake` file, and then it worked:

```
# lib/tasks/migration_hooks.rb

namespace :db do
  task set_role_postsgres: :environment do
    puts "Setting Role to 'postgres'"
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET ROLE postgres")
  end
end

Rake::Task["db:load_config"].enhance ["db:set_role_postsgres"]
```

Note: The `db:load_config` task is a prerequisite for all `db` tasks, so this should handle setting the role for not only `db:migrate`, but also `db:migrate:up`, `db:migrate:down`, `db:rollback`, etc.

Comment: This worked for a project that was using ActiveRecord 5.2 but it's not working for a project that's using ActiveRecord 6.0. Has anything changed that would make this not work?

Comment: I created 2 identical Rails projects but one version 6 and the other 5.2 and this method worked for the earlier one but failed to work on 6. Not sure why, but this answer is, unfortunately, deprecated at Rails version 6.

Comment: while showing same symptoms i did not have to jump through this particular loop. Simply adding user: postgres was enough.

Answer (score 0):

I just found myself needing such functionality, but for all `ActiveRecord` connections. In a Rails v7 application I used the following monkey-patch:

```rb
module PostgreSQLAdapterWithSetRole
  def initialize(connection, logger, connection_parameters, config)
    super(connection, logger, connection_parameters, config)

    if config[:role]
      connection.exec("SET ROLE #{config[:role]};")
    end
  end
end

ActiveRecord::ConnectionAdapters::PostgreSQLAdapter.prepend(PostgreSQLAdapterWithSetRole)
```

This reads a `role` configuration value from `database.yml` and if set issues `SET ROLE` immediately after the connection is established.